# Calling 'git pull' from a git post-update hook

Tags: git, shell, githooks

I have a central git repo set up using gitolite.

I want to set up a hook such that whenever a user pushes to the repo, it performs a pull elsewhere followed by some automated testing.

So far, I only want to it perform the pull.

In the hooks directory I created the following script names post-update:

```
#!/bin/sh  
cd /home/git/www/epicac
git pull
```

When I invoke this script using ./post-update, it does exactly what I want.

However, whenever it's invoked automatically as I hook, I get: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Just added the `env -i git pull` solution.

Comment: have exactly the same problem, even after 7 years

Answer (score 28):

You have various diagnostics to run as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314500/git-post-receive-hook-not-working).

In particular, [check out the the value of `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`](https://serverfault.com/questions/107608/git-post-receive-hook-with-git-pull-failed-to-find-a-valid-git-directory/107703#107703).

> While the hook is running, `GIT_DIR` and (if the worktree can't be inferred from `GIT_DIR`) `GIT_WORK_TREE` are set.
>   **That means your pull won't run with the repository in the directory you changed to.**

---

See also blog post [Using Git Inside a Git Hook](http://jakescruggs.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-git-inside-git-hook.html):

> Eventually we got our linux guru over and he noticed that the environment under which the git user runs is totally different when inside a hook.
>   Gitolite  does a bunch of things to the env, but the one that was screwing us up was the setting of the `GIT_DIR`.
>   After we figured that out, the solution was as easy as:

```
ENV.delete 'GIT_DIR'
```

> in our ruby script that is triggered by the '`post-receive`' hook.

---

Same deal in  
[Git Tip: Auto update working tree via post-receive hook](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-tip-auto-update-working-tree-via-post-receive-hook:49551efe-6414-4e86-aec6-544f4834cda3), but with an elegant way out of this:

> The solution?
>   **It turns out the `post-receive` hook starts out with the `GIT_DIR` environment variable set to the `repo/.git` folder, so no matter what path you 'cd' into it will always try to run any following git commands there**.
>   Fixing this is simply a matter of unsetting the `GIT_DIR`
>   (thanks to Ulrich Petri for the **elegant `env -i` solution**):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ..
env -i git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 7):

How about specifying the `--git-dir`.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/git/www/epicac
git --git-dir=.git pull
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind... found it here: https://serverfault.com/questions/107608/git-post-receive-hook-with-git-pull-failed-to-find-a-valid-git-directory

Comment: VonC linked that in his above answer. either accept your answer or his one so it'll be helpful to other people looking at this question

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick in just one line:

```
git -C /home/git/www/epicac pull
```