# from command line ok but the hook (git)

Tags: git, githooks

I want to automatically update my redmine project repository after anybody pushes into remote repo. Currently gin in redmine is up and works fine. But after automatic update using a hook I get `The entry or revision was not found in the repository.` in redmine.

To set up git in redime I followed [redmine wiki](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/RedmineRepositories) so the repo is bare created via `git clone --bare`

To update redmine's git repository I use this **`cd /srv/www/redmine.domain.com/git_repositories/linode.git && git fetch && git reset --soft refs/remotes/origin/master`**

- manual update if running from command line under `git` user works ok

the screenshot when executed manually is

```
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From domain.com:linode
  * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
```

- the same doesn't work correctly when running form `post-receive` hook (see the error above). Runs under the same user (git). The first line of the hook is `#!/bin/sh`

**configuration:** git (1.7.0.4) + gitolite (1.5.7) on ubuntu

I checked the GIT_DIR system variable byt command SET
    remote: /srv/www/redmine.domain.com/git_repositories/linode.git[K
    remote: GIT_DIR='.'[K

I even tried to set `git path` up in the hook by

```
export GIT_DIR=/srv/www/redmine.domain.com/git_repositories/linode.git
or unset GIT_DIR
```

but nothing helped.

The result of the hook

```
echo "Post receive-hook => updating Redmine repository"
#env -i git reset --hard
#unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
#unset GIT_DIR


cd /srv/www/redmine.domain.com/git_repositories/linode.git
pwd
git fetch
git reset --soft refs/remotes/origin/master
```

is

```
Pushing to git@domain.com:linode
remote: Post receive-hook => updating Redmine repository[K
remote: From domain.com:linode[K
remote: /srv/www/redmine.domain.com/git_repositories/linode.git[K
remote:    4755447..13b8e3d  master     -> origin/master[K
To git@domain.com:linode
  4755447..13b8e3d  master -> master
```

I tried few hints from [calling-git-pull-from-a-git-post-update-hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542854/calling-git-pull-from-a-git-post-update-hook) and [git-post-receive-hook-with-git-pull-failed-to-find-a-valid-git-directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/107608/git-post-receive-hook-with-git-pull-failed-to-find-a-valid-git-directory) but nothing helped

### Update

if I try

```
echo "Post receive-hook => updating Redmine repository"
export GIT_DIR=

cd /srv/www/domain.com/git_repositories/linode.git

echo "Resetting working tree..."
git reset --hard
echo "Finished resetting working tree."

git fetch
git reset --soft refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I get this + redmine repository is untouched and accessible from redmine

```
Pushing to git@domain.com:linode
remote: Post receive-hook => updating Redmine repository[K
remote: Resetting working tree...[K
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: ''[K
remote: Finished resetting working tree.[K
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: ''[K
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: ''[K
To git@domain.com:linode
 c553a15..854d159  master -> master
```

### Update2

I found out that if I do `git fetch` from the hook and then `git reset --soft refs/remotes/origin/master` from command line it doesn't work. I get the above error in redmine. I do `git fetch` from command line then everything works fine. Console messages from both hook and commnand line 'git fetch` commands looks the same to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work correctly"? I see output from the fetch; it looks like it succeeded. `git reset --soft` doesn't produce any output if it runs successfully. At the top you say you get that error - what command prompts that? Is it within Redmine? (And is the redmine repo bare? If not, remember that `git reset --soft` doesn't touch index or working tree...)

Comment: @Jefromi: I updated my question...hopefully it is clearer now. My point is that if I run the `git fetch && git reset --soft` from a command line it works (=I can see updated repo from redmine) if fired from the hook I get the error in redmine.

Comment: You might want to put some debugging statements in your hook script, like print out the directory it's in and echo the commands before they run (or use -x on the shebang line). Anything printed to stdout/stderr by the hook script will be sent back to the remote.

Comment: @ebneter: thanks, I updated my question. pwd gives me the right path I believe. It seems to me that `git` command is not executed properly as there is no git output when hook is executed. Compare to manual execution.

Comment: what does it mean to 'use -x on the shebang line'?

Comment: Try adding a pwd command right after the cd, to have the script print the directory you're actually in. My guess is that the script isn't changing to the correct directory. As for the "shebang line",  it's the line at the top of your script that looks like #!/bin/bash or something similar. The "-x" option tells bash (or sh) to echo all the commands before executing them.

Comment: I did the pwd, even before posting my question. It is in the correct directory. If the correct directory is the .git (repository) directory. In my case ~/srv/www/redmine.domain.com/git_repositories/linode.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do know exactly what and why but after `git fetch` executed via hook (I use gitolite) some files (maybe new ones) has permissions that redmine `doesn't like.

```
chmod -R 770 redmine_repo.git
```

did the trick