# git fetch works from command line but not from the hook

Tags: git

I was thinking whether the question belongs here or on SO. 4 days ago I created a question [from command line ok but the hook (git)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144853/from-command-line-ok-but-the-hook-git)  on SO. So far no answer.

To make it quick and simple.... I want to fire '**post receive**' when somebody does push to my remote repository. The hook will fetch the new stuff into another repository. Why? Redmine needs it like that so this repository is browse able.

- when I run all necessary commands from the **command line** everything works.
- when I run the same commands from the hook

  - there is no output from git when the hook executes git fetch
  - redmine tells '**The entry or revision was not found in the repository**.'

I tried lots of stuff to make it work and have no idea what to do next :-)

Please read [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144853/from-command-line-ok-but-the-hook-git) for more details.

Comment: Should your question title say `"git fetch works from command line but not the hook"` (add the word "not")?

Comment: to be honest ... English is not my first language and I was thinking about 'adding not'. I thought that but negates whatever is before but....

Comment: "When I do a `git fetch`, everything but the hook works." or "everything works, except the hook". I see what you meant but Dennis is right, it would be clearer with a "not"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do know exactly what and why but after `git fetch` executed via hook (I use gitolite) some files (maybe new ones) has permissions that redmine `doesn't like.

```
chmod -R 770 redmine_repo.git
```

did the trick