# execute git command inside bash script

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I am writing `gitosis` post-push hook for central repository

which pulls updates from central repository to testing enviroment

`nano /var/git/repositories/holding.git/hooks/post-update`

```
 #!/bin/bash

 cd /var/vh/holding;
 git reset --hard;
 git checkout testing;
 git pull;
```

here what I get after push on my client (development VM)

```
# blah ...
Counting objects: 57, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Writing objects: 100% (30/30), 3.42 KiB, done.
Total 30 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
To git@cheby.ru:holding.git
   233b5a2..0f46cd8  testing -> testing
```

Obviously, my attempt to tell git, where it should do pull, failed.

What is correct way to run git command for a specified working copy in bash script?

Comment: It is possible, perhaps even documented (need to check man page) that GIT_DIR is set to '.' while processing your hook function....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542854/calling-git-pull-from-a-git-post-update-hook) or [there](https://serverfault.com/questions/107608/git-post-receive-hook-with-git-pull-failed-to-find-a-valid-git-directory), you could precede all your git commands with:

```
 env -i
```

in order to make sure there is no side effect with, for instance, a `GIT_DIR` environment variable which could have been previously set.
(`env -i` or simply: `unset GIT_DIR`)

Answer (score 2):

For me, preceding with `env -i` does not work. I always get this error:

> *** Please tell me who you are.

Although I've set the global config. This is what works for me by specifying `--git-dir` parameter:

```
#!/bin/sh

GIT='git --git-dir='$PWD'/.git'

$GIT checkout hotfix
$GIT merge --no-ff master -m "Merged master"
$GIT push
```

I run the script inside the working directory hence I use `$PWD` to get current working directory. You may adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Is `/var/vh/holding` a git repository?  i.e. have you run `git init` on it, set up your remotes, set it to track your holding.git directory, etc.?  Also, if you're not pulling from the same repo you're pushing to, you shouldn't need the `reset` and `checkout`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `--git-dir` parameter to specify the path to `.git`.

For example: we can call `git log` like this:

```
git --git-dir=<path to git cloned dir>/.git log
```