# Getting “fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree?” on bare repository

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm a newbie when it comes to git and i went through some video tutorials [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaSDIdNkCDQ)

After seeing these tutorials i tried to set up a git repo with my friend using ssh

Note:

- We are using mac snow leopard
- The Git version is 1.7.5.4

I managed to set up my code in a folder lets say 'folder1' using

```
git init
```

which has my code files .

Then I create an empty repository on my friends machine lets say '`folder2`', and I made `folder2` a bare repository using

```
git init --bare --shared
```

Now I wanted  to setup the shared repo as the repository for `folder1`'s code
After this, I tried to add the remote on the bare repo using ssh

```
git remote add origin myFriend@hisIp:/LocationToFile
```

After this, I pushed the code which gave me a successful message

Now the issue is that the git repo '`folder2`' is still show an empty repo (with the folders of an empty repository) and I cant perform git operations in `folder2` as 
even if I do "`git status`", I get "`fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it is a bare repo, it has no working tree. See "[What's the -practical- difference between a Bare and non-Bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540883/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-bare-and-non-bare-repository)".

You should clone locally that folder2 repo, in order to execute your commands.

```
# on server:
cd /path/to/folder2
git clone folder2 folder2b
cd folder2b
git status
```

Note: It would be best to follow the naming convention for bare repo directory: `folder2.git` (instead of `folder2`)

Comment: I had similar issue when I began working from a new session.  Found out it was the GIT_DIR variable causing it.  Unset solved it.

Comment: @Rich True: I mentioned a similar issue in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6123109/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/17505437/6309