# Git - push failure / This operation must be run in a work tree

Tags: git

I'm following the Git Pro book ( http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server ) to set up my first git remote server on Ubuntu.
After I follow this:

```
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/inventory.git
$ git push origin Windows
```

I receive this message:

```
Counting objects: 33, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28,28) done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 7.30 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 33 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@gitserver:/opt/git/inventory.git
 * [new branch]    Windows -> Windows
```

But when I type `git status`on the remote server (in /opt/git/inventory.git/) I get the error message `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

The remote repository appears to not contain any of the files from the local repository and when I clone the remote repository into a different local folder there are no files, just the .git folder.

I have looked at other related questions on here:

[fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262801/fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree)

[Why am I getting the message, "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456923/why-am-i-getting-the-message-fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree)

[Getting “fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree?” on bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931840/getting-fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree-on-bare-repository)

but am no clearer as to why this is happening and what i can do to remedy it.

Comment: Read up on `bare` repositories. By definition a `bare` repository doesn't have a work tree, speaks no checked out files. This is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The remote repository in question is a [bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5540883/1860929).

It will only contain the packed objects and refs etc that git internally stores and won't have any of the regular code files checked out. As such, there will be no working tree, and hence no working `git status`.

That said, to check if your changes were pushed, just clone that repo in question to another location, and you will find your files all right:

```
git clone /opt/git/inventory.git some/location/inventory_clone
```

You might need to do a `git checkout master` in the newly cloned repo to actually see the code files.

Comment: when I clone the repository I get the following: `warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.` and there are no files in the cloned repository?

Comment: @RMPhoenix After you clone the repo, do a `git checkout master`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15631690/1860929)

Comment: Aha! OK, thankyou, I've got it.  I pushed my local repo to my remote server, pulled it back down into a different local folder `inventory_clone` which created another folder `inventory', in that folder I did `git branch -a` to see what branches there were and then `git checkout` on the branch i wanted and there the files were.  Thankyou very much @mu I shall read deeper into Git, I think I need to better understand what it is fundamentally doing here.

Comment: Thankyou very much!