# Permissions on post receive-hook

Tags: git, permissions, git-post-receive

I try to copy the content of a Git Repo from my VPS Homedirectoy into my public_html Folder.

So i've createt a post-receive hook with:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/domainname/public_html git checkout -f
```

And i've set its permission with:

```
chmod +x post-receive
```

But nothing happens. So i've set the permissions of public_html to:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data myUser
$ sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/domainname/public_html
```

Doesnt work either. I've already tried some of the solutions proposed here on stackoverflow regarding permissions without success. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But nothing happens.

You need to make sure the hook is actually executed (by adding, for instance, an `echo "test"`) in it.

You also can touch a file (to see if it is created/updated), as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14924839).

Finally, just to be sure, [I usually set `GIT_DIR` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532602).

Comment: I used echo to test and changed the permissions on my public_html and it worked. not completly sure why... thx