# fatal: Not a git repository: '.git' error

Tags: git, hook, git-bash

I have created a pre-commit hook which takes the database dump and saves it in a file under my application/folder  which is also in the git repo, after saving it I add the file to commit list . Following is the code in my pre-commit file

```
    D:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -pxyz --skip-extended-insert [database] > D:/xampp/htdocs/app/application/[database].sql

cd D:/xampp/htdocs/app/application
git add [database].sql
```

I tried to run the pre-commit code directly through command prompt it works without any error but when I try to commit the code through git bash I get this error

```
fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'
```

I am assuming its because of the git command used in the pre-commit file, can anyone tell me whats wrong in this file and how I should amend it

Comment: `cd D:/...` won't take you to the `D:` drive (if you're not there yet).

Comment: Are you sure the pre-commit hook is though?

Comment: yup, pre commit hook is written under .git file which is under my app directory and all of them are under d drive

Comment: How are you making sure of that? Where the script resides has nothing to do with what environment it will be started in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In doubt, in your hook, set up explicitly `git-dir` and `work-tree` parameters:

```
git --git-dir .git --work-tree . add ...
```

You can even put the full path to be extra-sure:

```
git --git-dir D:/xampp/htdocs/app/application/.git --work-tree D:/xampp/htdocs/app/application/. add ...
```

That way, you rule out any environment issue with those `git-dir` or `work-tree` stuck into another path which isn't the one of the repo your are cd'ing into.
See "[Calling '`git pull`' from a `git post-update` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542854/calling-git-pull-from-a-git-post-update-hook)" for an example of that problem.

Comment: can you direct me to link or can you explain me why was this happening ? @vonc

Comment: @AnandJoshi the link I mention in my answer is a good illustration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542854/calling-git-pull-from-a-git-post-update-hook . Your hook start with the wrong path for the git dir or work tree. Whenever you change directory into *another* repo from an hook, it is best to set explicitly those values (git dir and work tree) to the target repo you want to operate on.

Answer (score 1):

i had the exact same issue like you and found this solution:

instead of doing

```
cd D:/xampp/htdocs/app/application
git add [database].sql
```

i simply did

```
git add D:/xampp/htdocs/app/application/[database].sql
```

that way i didn't irritate git by cd-ing into another folder :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're in directory which have .git folder ?
to make sure, try to run

```
git status
```

and see what's happen. if you still get such message, I think your git hasn't been set up yet.

follow those steps to set up it:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "your message"
git push
```

Comment: what do you get when running git status ?

Comment: modified : aplication/[database].sql that is because the sql dump is created every time commit command is done, @kevin do you have any experience with hooks ?