# fatal: Not a git repository: '.git' error when git pre-commit hook fires but runs fine on commandline

Tags: git, laravel, version-control, githooks

I cloned an existing project on my local.

I have a pre-commit bash script that is in the .git/hooks folder.

This is what it looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd api && php artisan enforcer:check --githook
```

I am changing into the api folder since my git root is one level up and api contains the laravel framework where I can use the php artisan commands.

Whenever I commit something on the commandline, When I go to the line in my code that says:

```
$projectGitRoot = trim(shell_exec("git rev-parse --show-toplevel"));
```

it gives me fatal: Not a git repository: '.git' error.

Whenever I run the actual pre-commit on command line by doing ./.git/hooks/pre-commit, it works just fine.

I then changed the pre-commit to use Sudo and everything works (but this is not a good solution)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd api && sudo php artisan enforcer:check --githook
```

I have verified using whoami that in both cases it is the same user. I have tried chowning the .git folder with my commandline user. Nothing works.

What can I do? I looked at other questions like [fatal: Not a git repository: '.git' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914933/fatal-not-a-git-repository-git-error)

but still very lost.

UPDATE:

It appears that the git pre-commit hook does not want to do anything with GIT. It cant even return a git status.

Comment: Does `api` folder is another local git repo or it's just a folder for laravel project? And where did you execute the command `$projectGitRoot = trim(shell_exec("git rev-parse --show-toplevel"));`, api folder or the parent folder?

Comment: api folder is just for laravel. That is run in api folder since that is where the php artisan command will work. Thats why I did a 'cd api && php artisan...' because my understanding is that the git hook executes in the git root folder so I would need to do a cd into the api.   Works ok with sudo. without it the same error.

Comment: What's the directory if you print the `$projectGitRoot` in pre-commit hook?

Comment: /Users/jini/apps/laravel_apps/MyAppName          Under this are folders like api, .git etc.

Comment: Try `unset GIT_DIR`  - like the top answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043609/getting-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-using-post-update-hook-to-execut

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my post-checkout hook:

```
fatal: not a git repository: '.git'
```

I fixed it by only running git commands in the working directory that the hook script started in. The first `git rev-parse` below is before `pushd` changes directories, and the second one is after `popd` switches back to the original directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/mydir
# Do something inside mydir.
./do_something.sh
# Run git commands in the original directory.
popd
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```