# Why does `git` commands fail when run as part of a git hook in a subfolder?

Tags: node.js, git, husky, git-husky

We recently moved a Node project into a subfolder of a mono-repo, and after that our commit hooks (installed using Husky) started failing due to being executed in the wrong directory:

```
{ Error: Command failed: git rev-parse HEAD
fatal: not a git repository: '.git'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:297:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:395:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:611:12)
  killed: false,
  code: 128,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'git rev-parse HEAD' }
```

I didn't have problems fixing the issue (basically `cd`-ing to the root directory before executing any `git` commands in the hooks), but what I don't get is **why does the (unfixed) scripts work on the command line - regardless of which folder I execute them from?**.

The failing parts of the script is basically:

```
console.log('PWD', cp.execSync('pwd'));
console.log(cp.execSync('git rev-parse HEAD'));
```

Project layout

```
.git/
frontend/
  package.json
backend/
```

Example command that will trigger the error above:

```
git checkout master
```

Apart from the error, it prints the working directory: `PWD /tmp/foo/myproj/frontend`

If I manually trigger the script, everything works fine:

```
npm run postcheckout
PWD /tmp/foo/myproj/frontend

82dc6d2089a397f0889addb562ea84ba8d846215
```

This works no matter if the root folder or a sub-folder, and I cannot really see the difference. Husky is supposed to find the `.git` folder, and this seems to prove it, but obviously something changes when it is run as a hook script. The relevant parts of the auto-generated Husky script is:

```
cd "frontend"
...
...
npm run postcheckout
```

- [fatal: Not a git repository: '.git' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914933/fatal-not-a-git-repository-git-error/11915540#11915540)
- https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/348
- https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/167

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: unset `$GIT_DIR` (in sh script, `unset GIT_DIR`).

There is a hint in [the githooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks/):

> Before Git invokes a hook, it changes its working directory to either $GIT_DIR in a bare repository or the root of the working tree in a non-bare repository. An exception are hooks triggered during a push (*pre-receive*, *update*, *post-receive*, *post-update*, *push-to-checkout*) which are always executed in $GIT_DIR.

plus another few in [the top level Git manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git):

> **--git-dir=<path>**
> Set the path to the repository. This can also be controlled by setting the `GIT_DIR` environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.
>
> `GIT_DIR`
> If the `GIT_DIR` environment variable is set then it specifies a path to use instead of the default `.git` for the base of the repository. The `--git-dir` command-line option also sets this value.

What happens here is that the top level Git *program* sets `$GIT_DIR` to the path by which the `.git` directory is to be found.  Since the hook has changed its working directory to the work-tree, the Git program has set `$GIT_DIR` to `.git`.  If you `chdir` elsewhere, you must adjust `$GIT_DIR` appropriately—and if you chdir completely away from the main repository and wish to have Git *discover* `$GIT_DIR` again, you must *unset* `$GIT_DIR`.