# git pull while not in a git directory

Tags: git

Let's say I have a directory, `/X/Y`, which is a git repository. Is it possible to somehow call a command like `git pull` from inside `/X`, but targeting the `/X/Y` directory?

**EDIT:** I guess I was wondering specifically: is it possible to do this using the a git command, but without having to change directories?

**NOTE:** I've accepted [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory/20115526#20115526) as it's much more elegant than previous options. For people running Git older than 1.8.5, please see [bstpierre's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory/5083437#5083437).

Comment: I'd like to add that when using git-pull within a hook will not work unless you unset GIT_DIR.
[Relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043609/getting-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-using-post-update-hook-to-execut)

Comment: Starting git 1.8.5 (Q4 2013), you will be able to "use a git command, but without having to change directories". See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20115526/6309)

Comment: Just use following example command
> git -C "<dirPath>" pull

Answer (score 521, accepted):

Starting [git 1.8.5 (Q4 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5fd09df3937f54c5cfda4f1087f5d99433cce527/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L115-L116), you will be able to "use a Git command, but without having to change directories".

> Just like "`make -C <directory>`", **"`git -C <directory> ...`" tells Git to go there before doing anything else**.

See [commit 44e1e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44e1e4d67d5148c245db362cc48c3cc6c2ec82ca) by **[Nazri Ramliy](http://perlresume.org/NAZRI)**:

> It takes more keypresses to invoke Git command in a different directory without leaving the current directory:
>
> 1. `(cd ~/foo && git status)
>
>      git --git-dir=~/foo/.git --work-tree=~/foo status
>
>      GIT_DIR=~/foo/.git GIT_WORK_TREE=~/foo git status`
> 2. `(cd ../..; git grep foo)`
> 3. `for d in d1 d2 d3; do (cd $d && git svn rebase); done`
>
> The methods shown above are acceptable for scripting but are too cumbersome for quick command line invocations.
>
> With this new option, the above can be done with fewer keystrokes:
>
> 1. `git -C ~/foo status`
> 2. `git -C ../.. grep foo`
> 3. `for d in d1 d2 d3; do git -C $d svn rebase; done`

---

Since Git 2.3.4 (March 2015), and [commit 6a536e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a536e2076f02a98e0d6403ff68f3acf717fa1c4) by [Karthik Nayak (`KarthikNayak`)](https://github.com/KarthikNayak), `git` will treat "`git -C '<path>'`" as a **no-op when `<path>` is empty.**

> '`git -C ""`' unhelpfully dies with error "`Cannot change to ''`", whereas the shell treats cd ""' as a no-op.
>   Taking the shell's behavior as a precedent, teach `git` to treat -C ""' as a no-op, as well.

---

4 years later, Git 2.23 (Q3 2019)  documents that '`git -C ""`' works and doesn't change directory

> It's been behaving so since 6a536e2 (`git`: treat "`git -C '<path>'`"
>   as a no-op when `<path>` is empty, 2015-03-06, Git v2.3.4).

That means [the documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1a64e07d235579ae0b3bc6d1f081a51a6e48a4d1/Documentation/git.txt#L59-L60) now (finally) includes:

> If '`<path>`' is present but empty, e.g. `-C ""`, then the current working directory is left unchanged.

---

You can see `git -C` used with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), as an example.

See [commit b441717](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b44171725646880db07cbee6446e15b4afaa1930), [commit 9291e63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9291e6329ef3333f9447b0b4cdec0607e00c39cf), [commit 5236fce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5236fce6b4b597588f5e3955b309195f376a858f), [commit 10812c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10812c2337eb04f2857000fd644efdc02247ca92), [commit 62d58cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62d58cda69621eb2f70517c87f1baeeb7b2f398c), [commit b87b02c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b87b02cfe6973ac8cc778e0463bc3ad6accb96a6), [commit 9b92070](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b92070e5231773f564c1fe631cddd6d436963a5), [commit 3595d10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3595d10c26db483239d97ca8fc435c1c9dabcfb1), [commit f511bc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f511bc02edc8e2729e7babb1b4caa98684d941bc), [commit f6041ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6041abdcd7bfefed1cbe14cbe221f0e848cbec4), [commit f46c243](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f46c243e669f5f1e6ef2f25000d5a5f593d2e1f3), [commit 99c049b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99c049bc4c029471af5efcbd1a4ca1fd4a45b923), [commit 3738439](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3738439c7779acf2dafadbbc488bb222c94a2b12), [commit 7717242](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7717242014dc59f58db7e56c2b8f9fc79e04fa0b), [commit b8afb90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8afb908c261752310d4792f901c68fe27b77b40) (20 Dec 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 381e8e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/381e8e9de142b636e4a25b6df113d70168e21a34), 05 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`t1507`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b44171725646880db07cbee6446e15b4afaa1930): inline `full_name()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>
>
> Before, we were running `test_must_fail full_name`. However, `test_must_fail` should only be used on git commands.
>   Inline `full_name()` so that we can use `test_must_fail` on the `git` command directly.
>
> When `full_name()` was introduced in [28fb84382b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28fb84382b0eb728534dbe2972bbfec3f3d83dd9) ("Introduce `<branch>@{upstream}` notation", 2009-09-10, Git v1.7.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ca1b623865a9dc100f95a7867e35a9f73d7507a)), the `git -C` option wasn't available yet (since it was introduced in [44e1e4d67d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44e1e4d67d5148c245db362cc48c3cc6c2ec82ca) ("`git`: run in a directory given with -C option", 2013-09-09, Git v1.8.5-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/087350398e8b2c5d4b39f051b23a2e533f4d830b) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/128a96c98442524c7f2eeef4757b1e48445f24ce))).
>   As a result, the helper function removed the need to manually `cd` each time. However, since `git -C` is available now, we can just use that instead and inline `full_name()`.

Comment: Does not work for me:


   # git --version && git -C ~/.m2/ checkout master
   git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)
   Unknown option: -C
   usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]

Comment: @JanGalinski But I did mention "Starting git 1.8.5". So git 1.8.3.x wouldn't know yet about that option.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 I had to install a newer git version. I did it like this: `apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties` then add the git repo `add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`. The last step is to update git: `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Argh crap CentOS 6.6.

Comment: @avesus no problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21820715/6309 or http://serverfault.com/a/604124/783 or https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-the-latest-git-version-on-centos

Comment: Doing this on many folders with wildcards does not work... `git -C */default pull` :-( Anyone?

Comment: @Jonny I agree, it won't work (even in bash shell). You would need to wrap it with for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13337546/6309

Comment: After various failed attempts e.g `--git-dir=foo/.git`, `--work-tree=foo`, the `-C` option seems to cover it, thanks.

Comment: cannot use the `~` in the path, use the `$HOME` or full path or relative path will be ok.

Comment: @XinMeng Strange: what OS and git version are you using?: `~` works just fine when used with `-C`.

Comment: @VonC I am using Fedora 26

Comment: @XinMeng And which version of Git?

Comment: @VonC git version 2.13.6

Comment: @XinMeng Seems recent enough. A `git -C ~/path/to/other/git/repo remote -v` should work.

Answer (score 59):

**Edit**:

There's either a bug with `git pull`, or you can't do what you're trying to do with that command. You *can* however, do it with fetch and merge:

```
cd /X
git --git-dir=/X/Y/.git fetch
git --git-dir=/X/Y/.git --work-tree=/X/Y merge origin/master
```

**Original answer**:

Assuming you're running bash or similar, you can do `(cd /X/Y; git pull)`.

The [git man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) specifies some variables (see "The git Repository") that seem like they should help, but I can't make them work right (with my repository in /tmp/ggg2):

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/tmp/ggg2 GIT_DIR=/tmp/ggg2/.git git pull
fatal: /usr/lib/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.
```

Running the command below while my cwd is /tmp updates that repo, but the updated file appears in /tmp instead of the working tree /tmp/ggg2:

```
GIT_DIR=/tmp/ggg2/.git git pull
```

See also [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505467/can-i-store-the-git-folder-outside-the-files-i-want-tracked), which demonstrates the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` flags.

Comment: Did you try using just GIT_WORK_TREE?

Comment: @Arrowmaster: yes, if you do that, git can't find the `.git` directory.

Comment: Ah right, the man page says that GIT_WORK_TREE is not used if GIT_DIR is not set. It seems strange that its not working then when both are used.

Comment: @Arrowmaster: I have to wonder if there's a bug here somewhere. If I do `git --git-dir=/tmp/ggg2/.git --work-tree=/tmp/ggg2 pull`, I get an error message. But if I do `git --git-dir=/tmp/ggg2/.git --work-tree=. pull` while I'm in /tmp, it puts the updated files in /tmp as it should.

Comment: @bstpierre: I don't have access to a system with git installed right now but if I did I would be trying other alternatives with `--work-tree` right now like `--work-tree=/tmp/ggg2/` and `--work-tree=/tmp/ggg2/.` since it could be an issue with how its parsing the path.

Comment: @bstpierre: Also what version of git are you trying this on?

Comment: Thanks, your edited answers helped. Spent an hour playing with git pull and various options and `cd`s until I tried your solution and it worked

Comment: I'm using git v1.7.9.5 and `git --git-dir=${HOME}/repo/.git pull` works fine.

Answer (score 34):

You may wrap it in a bash script or git alias:

```bash
cd /X/Y && git pull && cd -
```

Comment: This definitely does the trick, but I'm wondering if there's some way to use the git command without changing directories. I'm starting to think that there isn't.

Comment: and use the `pushd/popd` pair instead of `cd/cd-`

Comment: Or you could use a subshell to prevent having to cd back: `(cd xyz && git pull)`

Answer (score 32):

This post is a bit old so could be there was a bug andit was fixed, but I just did this:

```
git --work-tree=/X/Y --git-dir=/X/Y/.git pull origin branch
```

And it worked. Took me a minute to figure out that it wanted the dotfile and the parent directory (in a standard setup those are always parent/child but not in ALL setups, so they need to be specified explicitly.

Comment: I like this solution because it works with directories like \\remotemachine\C$\folder\etc

Answer (score 7):

As some of my servers are on an old Ubuntu LTS versions, I can't easily upgrade git to the latest version (which supports the -C option as described in some answers).

This trick works well for me, especially because it does not have the side effect of some other answers that leave you in a different directory from where you started.

```
pushd /X/Y
git pull
popd
```

Or, doing it as a one-liner:

```
pushd /X/Y; git pull; popd
```

Both Linux and Windows have pushd and popd commands.

Answer (score 6):

Using combination `pushd`, `git pull` and `popd`, we can achieve this functionality:

```
pushd <path-to-git-repo> && git pull && popd
```

For example:

```
pushd "E:\Fake Directory\gitrepo" && git pull && popd
```

Comment: this is amazing. Works perfectly

Answer (score 4):

You can write a script like this:

```bash
cd /X/Y
git pull
```

You can name it something like `gitpull`.
If you'd rather have it do arbitrary directories instead of `/X/Y`:

```bash
cd $1
git pull
```

Then you can call it with `gitpull /X/Z`
Lastly, you can try finding repositories.  I have a `~/git` folder which contains repositories, and you can use this to do a pull on all of them.

```bash
g=`find /X -name .git`
for repo in ${g[@]}
do
    cd ${repo}
    cd ..
    git pull
done
```

Comment: If you want to do it from the command line, just do it in a subshell: `(cd /X/Y && git pull)`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone like me that was trying to do this via a drush (Drupal shell) command on a remote server, you will not be able to use the solution that requires you to CD into the working directory:

Instead you need to use the solution that breaks up the pull into a fetch & merge:

```
drush @remote exec git --git-dir=/REPO/PATH --work-tree=/REPO/WORKDIR-PATH fetch origin
drush @remote exec git --git-dir=/REPO/PATH --work-tree=/REPO/WORKDIR-PATH merge origin/branch
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a similar problem, but you can also simply chain you commands. eg

On one line

```
cd ~/Sites/yourdir/web;git pull origin master
```

Or via SSH.

```
ssh username@atyourserver.com -t "cd ~/Sites/thedir/web;git pull origin master"
```