# Working on git repo without cd into directory

Tags: git

How would I run git commands on a repo when I have not `cd`'d into that directory?

I.e. I want to run `git branch /repos/myrepo.git`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pull while not in a git directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> `--git-dir=<path>`
>
> Set the path to the repository. This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_DIR environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html

Note that `<path>` above means the path to the actual git directory (`project_dir/.git`) not just the project directory (`project_dir`).

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work for me.
<pre> <code> git --git-dir=/Users/michael/Development/Projects/opensource/dvsc-backup/ </code> </pre>

Comment: Not a git repository.  It is one and everything works normally when I cd into the dir and run git commands on it.

Comment: Maybe `git --git-dir=/Users/michael/Development/Projects/opensource/dvsc-backup/.git`?

Comment: You must add the .git folder to the end of the --git-dir=<path> for this to work.  

Does not work:
    git --git-dir=/Users/michael/Development/Projects/opensource/dvsc-backup/

Works:
    git --git-dir=/Users/michael/Development/Projects/opensource/dvsc-backup/.git/ branch

Comment: If it's a bare repository you can just use the folder that you've cloned into (there is no .git folder anyway)

Answer (score 59):

Starting with git 1.8.5, use the `-C` option.

```
git -C "/Users/michael/Development/Projects/opensource/dvsc-backup" status
```

Otherwise, you have to specify `--work-tree` as well as `--git-dir`

```
git --work-tree="/Users/michael/Development/Projects/opensource/dvsc-backup" --git-dir="/Users/michael/Development/Projects/opensource/dvsc-backup/.git" status
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `-C "path/to/repo"` should be kept as the first argument

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer since it is more intuitive, no need to add `/.git` at the end.