# How to make current directory a git working directory

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I've written multiple *.cpp files in the location `~/Code/CPLUS` before I know the existence of git.

Now I want to use git for version control.

I created a folder `~/git_repo/`, and in this folder, I ran `git init` command. When I tried to run the command `git add my_first_c.cpp` under the path `~/Code/CPLUS`, the following message appeared:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Then I typed `git init ~/git_repo/` under the path `~/Code/CPLUS`, the same error still appeared when `git status` was typed.

If I type `git init` under the path `~/Code/CPLUS`, the `add` and `commit` can be executed. The only problem is that `.git` is stored in `~/Code/CPLUS/`, while I'd like it be stored in `~/git_repo`.

My question is how to make the folder `~/Code/CPLUS` a working directory while the repo info is stored in `~/git_repo/`? And my machine has no GUI.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060401/working-on-git-repo-without-cd-into-directory

Comment: Why would you want your git working directory to be anything other than the root directory of the source tree?  This isn't typically how you use git and I don't think what you want to do is a very smart way to use it.

Comment: @Alariva The suggested solution indeed solved my question. With `.git` created in `~/git_repo/`, typing `git --git-dir=~/git_repo/.git add my_first_c.cpp` works.

Comment: The solution to another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060401/working-on-git-repo-without-cd-into-directory) applies to this question, I don't know if this post should be closed or marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Alariva , the suggested solution indeed solved this question. With `.git` created in `~/git_repo/`, typing `git --git-dir=/abs/path/to/repo/git_repo/.git add my_first_c.cpp` works.

The solution comes from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060401/working-on-git-repo-without-cd-into-directory).

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting the variables `export GIT_WORK_TREE=~/git_repo/` and `export GIT_DIR=../Code/CPLUS` from terminal (or in your ~/.bashrc) so Git uses these.