# Git pull and specify directory?

Tags: git

i would like to run a git pull and specify the directory. some say using --git-dir and --work-tree should work but such as

```
git --git-dir=/var/www/.git --work-tree=/var/www pull
```

put this returns a "cannot be used without a working tree". The only time i can get this to work is if i use ".", ".." or any directory above the current directory

this post suggests maybe a bug?
[git pull while not in a git directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory)

in the end i need to run a sudo git pull in a single line. i welcome any work arounds. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use sudo and give the command as an argument to sh?

Something like:

```
sudo sh -c 'cd /dir && git pull'
```

Comment: perfect! thanks so much. combining w/ -i switch and sourcing the .bashrc file in .bash_profile i can even have a password on the private key. full command is [code](sudo -i -u www-data sh -c 'cd /var/www && git pull')

Comment: you can also wrap it with pushd & popd

Answer (score 22):

In the two years since this question was answered, Git 1.8 came out which supports calling `git` in other directories using the `-C` flag:

```
git -C /var/www pull
```

Comment: `git -C` documentation link: https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git--Cltpathgt

Answer (score 0):

You are using `--work-dir`, which is not the right paramter. It is `--work-tree` and should work for what you want. Or you can just do `cd /var/www && git pull` if you wanted the pull to be in a single command / line.

Comment: yeah sorry i am using the --work-tree param when i get that error (didn't copy the command in). ex: [code](git --git-dir=/var/www/.git --work-dir=/var/www pull). 

Other posts i have found seem to have the same issue. With no --work-tree specified it uses my home directory. I can specify --work-tree as ".", "..", "../.." (which is the / dir) w/o a problem but as soon as i go anywhere else it throws "cannot be used without a working tree". even using "../../var/www" will throw the error

Answer (score 0):

On Windows in MINGW64:

```
git -C "C:\Trunk190117\crewcontrol-source" pull
```

or

```
git -C /c/Trunk190117/crewcontrol-source pull
```