# Multiple git pull in one folder containing multiple repository

Tags: git, shell, github

I am using ubuntu and i have a folder gitrepos which has many clone of multiple git repos from github.

i want one script which can automatically do a git pull in all my repos.

say

```
[gitrepos]
  [repo1]
  [repo2]
  [repo3]
    ...
```

i want a script to do a git pull from all repox
note the repo name are different.

any  shell or py script available for this ?

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed, I had the exact same problem. There is no code to post, his question is more how to manage multiple git repositories and I feel that is clear

Comment: checkout out 'mr' as suggested by opqdonut. Steps
1) download mr and add it to your path
2) navigate to each git repo and type 'mr register'
3) type mr update and it will perform a git pull on all your repos. 
super handy, great question

Comment: `for d in *; do pushd $d; git pull; popd; done`

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at [mr](http://joeyh.name/code/mr/), a tool meant for exactly this.

Comment: fantastic tool. Works amazingly for me! I can now update all 34 repositories my team is working on in one line: "mr update"

Comment: This was precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: `apt install myrepos` -> Run `mr register` in each repository -> `mr update`

Answer (score 15):

Something line this would work:

From ~/gitrepos:

```
for REPO in `ls`; do (cd "$REPO"; git pull); done;
```

From anywhere:

```
for REPO in "`find ~/gitrepos -maxdepth 0 -type d`"; do (cd "$REPO"; git pull); done;
```

Comment: Rather than using a for loop over the output of find, you can do: `find ... -exec sh -c 'cd $0 && git pull' {} \;`

Comment: `ls *` appears to list the repo sub-directories when run from my `~/git/` folder. Probably not is what googlers are looking for.