# Run git commands in shell script without change directory to repo

Tags: git, shell, rvm

I'm writing a shell script (zsh) that will run git commands for a set of directories.  Some of these are projects with `.rvmrc` files which can take a while to run.  When I `cd` into the directory to run a command, it activates the `.rvmrc` which really slows down the script quite a bit.

Example command: `$(cd $dir && exec git branch)`

I would like to either run the commands without `cd`ing into the directory in my script, or temporarily deactivate the `.rvmrc` file so `cd`ing into the directory does not run the rvmrc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pull while not in a git directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory)

Comment: The proposed duplicate ('git pull while not in a git directory') seems to cover the same ground as the accepted (only) answer, but it isn't entirely clear how/why that evades the problems with Ruby's version manager (which is what `.rmvrc` files relate to, it seems).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can specify the git working directory and `.git` location:

```
git --work-tree=$dir --git-dir=$dir/.git branch
git -C $dir branch
```

There are also environmental parameter available, please check the [manuals](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/)