# Is there a delay in Git changing the file system?

Tags: bash, git

I have a small Bash script which includes some Git commands. (For certain reasons, I cannot use git hooks here.)

Basically, it does

```
git pull origin <<some repo>> || { echo "Git pull FAILED"; exit 1; }
# do something with the new/changed files on the file system
```

In not reproducible cases, this fails. In these cases, old versions of the files (being at the state before `git pull`) are used instead of the new files  (at the state after `git pull`).
However, if I manually do `git pull` and afterward run the other command, there was never any problem.

So, I'm now wondering if there is any delay/asynchronicity in Git changing the files on the file system after a pull. If yes: How can I deal with it (maybe avoiding `sleep` or something like that)? If not: What else could cause the confusion of file versions here?

Comment: Git operations are supposed to be atomic.  If so, this would imply that Git locks down the entire repo folder during a pull and only releases the lock if the entire pull were successful.  I can't find any literature to support this guess though.

Comment: Are you sure the `pull` command don't fail? That could explain why you still are in older version of the repo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the lock you mentioned protects the repo against concurrent Git operations. It doesn't prevent other programs reading or writing the files while Git is working.

Comment: @axiac Good to know.  Then there might not be a clean solution here.

Comment: This exact thing happened to me before. Here, refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839604/git-pull-and-then-push-via-cron-in-ubuntu

Comment: @Arount Yes, I'm sure that Git pull doesn't fail, since I handle that case. I've edit my code snippet showing that part.

Comment: You are not showing enough code for me to tell what's going wrong, but I will say: avoid `git pull`. *Especially* avoid it in any script. Break it into its two components, `git fetch` followed by (if fetch succeeds) `git merge`.