# Run git log from different directory

Tags: bash, git

I want to start `git-bash.exe`, and run `git log` from different directory.

I tried something like this:

```
"C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe" log -- C:\repos\foo
```

and this

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd=C:\repos\foo log
```

But none of theese works. Any ideas?

Comment: Would the [`--relative` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---relativeltpathgt) help?

Comment: @evolutionxbox tried `"C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe" --relative="C:/repos/foo"` but not working

Comment: You've missed the log command.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the problem is that git-bash window is closing after its being opened

Comment: Git-bash is a terminal which emulates BASH. It's not git itself.

Comment: @evolutionxbox good to know.

Comment: You can ignore my first comment as it is now wrong.

Comment: git-bash just starts an interactive bash environment. Why not using just git directly: `"c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -C aaa log`

Comment: @Serge I got error: `bash: C:\repos\foo: Is a directory` `/usr/bin/bash: Exit 126.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested, in a regular CMD session (no bash):

```
git -C C:\path\to\repo log
```

It does work just fine, using the [`-C` option I presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115526/6309), introduced in Git 1.8.5 (Q4 2013).