# Is git pull from another directory possible?

Tags: git, git-pull

I've different repository and want to keep all of them up to date. A solution can be `cd folder; git pull origin master` for all repositories. What I'm looking for is a way to do the same but without `cd` each times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git pull while not in a git directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have Git change into a directory automatically when it runs by passing the `-C` option, like so: `git -C DIR pull`.

Note that the `-C` option is a general Git option and not one to `git pull`, so it must be placed before `pull` and not after.

If you have a set of directories under the current directory, you can script this like so:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I{} git -C {} pull
```

Comment: I actually have done the exact same thing, but specifically looking for ".git" directories (then performing operations in their parent directory) and doing "remote update" instead of "pull". I've named it "fgru" and now have been using for years to update my repositories. :-)

Comment: Thenk you I think `-C DIR` is solving my problem.