# Accessing branches created by others in Git

Tags: git, github, branch

My partner and I are using Git to manage our code for our current project.
I made a branch called `test_func` that extends a function in the code (didn't know if it would work or not; that's why I did it on a branch).

However, my partner cannot access this branch from his local machine.
When he types `git branch`, it says that there is only one branch, `master`.

Is there any way I can make it to where he has access to the branch `test_func` as well? We both need to be able to read and write to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push it to a common **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26687327/6309)** in order for your colleague to fetch and check out:

```
# You (first push only)
git push -u origin test_func
```

The `-u` is to establish a remote tracking relationship between your local `test_func` branch and `origin/test_func`: see "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".
After thatinitial push, simple `git push` is enough.

```
# your colleague
...
git fetch
git checkout test_func
```

If you don't have one centralized bare repo, your colleague can add your repo as a remote, using a shared path.

```
# your colleague
git remote add you \\shared\path\to\your\repo
git fetch you
git checkout test_func
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the purpose of the `-u` when pushing? I've seen this before, but I usually just stick with

`git push origin master`

Should I always be using `-u` when pushing?

Comment: @Ryan I have edited the answer and link to http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309 which explains it in detail.