# git init will not create git directories for me

Tags: git, git-init

I am new to Git.
I can get a Git directory structure in a bare directory with `git -init --bare`.
I can see where the git information is stored.

However, when I try to use `git init` or even `git clone`, I never see any `.git` subdirectory in my local repository.  I can add files and push, but have no idea where those files are actually stored on disk for my local repository.

From the documentation:

> ```
> $ git init
> ```
>
> This creates a new subdirectory named `.git` that contains all of your necessary repository files – a Git repository skeleton.

However, I never see that skeleton directory.  I have used `dir -AH` to see if the git directory is hidden, but there is none. Why do I not get a git skeleton directory? And where, exactly are the added (staged) files put?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Except if you have used the `--git-dir` option when running "git init", your `.git` directory **MUST** be in the directory. Perhaps you should look more carefully.

In the same idea, perhaps have you set an environment variable `GIT_DIR` that change the place where the `.git` directory is stored. See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init Remove this env variable if it's the case.

And the added (staged) files are stored in the `index` file stored inside this  `.git` directory...

`dir -AH` (in powershell? otherwise it's `dir /AH`) works well for me...

Comment: And a rather simple way of making absolutely sure that there isn't anything hiding the `.git` directory is simply attempting to enter it: `cd .git`. If that works, it's clear the problem isn't actually with Git not creating the directory.

Comment: GIT_DIR was causing the git directory to be created elsewhere.  Thanks @Philippe.

Comment: That was a helpful suggestion @hvd.

Comment: Perfect! I was able to go inside /.git although it wasn't showing when we list all the files in a directory. @hvd

Answer (score 18):

On Windows, `git init` may create a hidden .git folder. Go to Organize --> Files and Search Options --> and then check Show Hidden Files. That will unveil the .git folder.

Comment: You rocked it. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add - you can unhide the .git folder by right clicking the folder > properties > general tab > untick the 'hidden' attribute

Answer (score 4):

Do

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

to see where git's finding the repository structure.

@VonC's got the goods on where the objects are, I'll just add that everything else is repo-local metadata.

Answer (score 3):

A `git init myrepo` would always create an empty `myrepo/` folder, with the `myrepo/.git` in it ready to get data.

A `git init --bare myrepo.git` is for creating a bare repo you can push to:

```
cd myrepo
git remote add origin ../myrepo.git
touch file.txt
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git push -u origin master
```

[image: http://www.ossxp.com/doc/gotgit-en/images/en/fig-13-03-git-clone-2.png]

<sup>(Picture from [gotgit](http://www.ossxp.com/doc/gotgit-en/))</sup>

You wouldn't see `file.txt` on `myrepo.git` [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) though, since a **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26687327/6309)** has no working tree (hence "bare")

In the repo, `myrepo/.git/objects` would contain the objects you are adding to the local repo: see [Git Internals - Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).
From [gotgit](http://www.ossxp.com/doc/gotgit-en/):

[image: http://www.ossxp.com/doc/gotgit-en/images/en/fig-06-02-git-repos-detail.png]

Comment: Thanks VonC!  The only reason I was creating a bare directory is because I saw in a couple places (including what I thought was official Git documentation) was that I "should" created a remote shared repository with bare.  I don't understand the reason for that suggestion.

Comment: @jmknpk that is why I mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684691/git-workflow-setting-up-a-build-process/26687327#26687327: to explain the bare repo best practice.

Answer (score 1):

I am ultimately attmepting to create remote and local repositories completely from scratch.  These are the commands I've used.  If anyone has suggestions I'd gladly hear them.

cd C:\Users\JimPC\Documents\pretendCloud

git init --bare Project1

cd C:\Users\JimPC\Documents\MyJava

git clone C:\Users\JimPC\Documents\pretendCloud\Project1 Project1

cd Project1

dir >File01.txt

git add File01.txt

git commit -m "Initial State Commit"

git push -u origin master

After these commands, I believe I am ready to continue building my project on the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, make sure you have your folder configured like this:

[image: Screenshot]

This is to show the hide elements

Comment: For the English version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78167671/2745495

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's simply not creating a repository.  I run these commands in Windows 7:

c:\Windows\System32>git init project1

Reinitialized existing Git repository in c:/Windows/System32/project1/.git/

c:\Windows\System32>cd project1

The system cannot find the path specified.

c:\Windows\System32>cd c:/Windows/System32/project1

The system cannot find the path specified.

c:\Windows\System32>git rev-parse --git-dir

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

c:\Windows\System32>

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, in the folder configurations, set View -> Hide selected items.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

if the directory is recornized then once you dissable the protection of pciif in case the git is installed in other then main drive and check again it will be created

Answer (score -1):

This command create a folder along with .git file

git init --bare localrepo.git

Comment: Hi Rohith! Welcome :) This is a duplicate of an of existing answer, by @VonC. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. Remember to review all existing answers first.