# What problem is trying to solve a Git --bare repo?

Tags: git, repository

I think I understood the *practical* difference between a **bare** and **non-bare** repo in Git, but I really don't get why *logically* this distinction exists: why Git had to implement the concept of bare and non-bare repos? I know there are already tons of thread and articles about the topic, but I am really missing some concrete examples to fully understand the topic.

To recap, the practical difference (i.e. in terms of files) between a non-bare and a bare repo should be the following:

- a **non-bare** repo is a combination of:

  1. a **.git** folder, that is a "special" folder that Git, as a software, uses to store all the data (e.g. blobs of the files of the project is versioning) and metadata (e.g. history of commits) to be able to work properly.
  2. a **working tree**, that is the actual files and folders that represent our project. One crucial thing to keep in mind is that the working tree isn't the only place where the content of your project is stored. The data of your project is saved by Git also inside the .git folder in a special format using some internal tools like [.git/objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28914471/6309). The working tree exists because it's the way everything that is not Git can work (hence the  name *working tree*) and edit the project files and folders.
- a **bare** repo is:

  1. the contents of the .git subdirectory right in the main directory itself
  2. no working tree

The question is: why do I need an intermediate bare repo to sync in a convenient way two non-bare repos? A lot of threads and articles are answering saying that not having a central bare repo would lead the central working tree to be out of sync (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49335973)). Ok, but why? Can someone provide a concrete example?

The situation I can imagine is the following:

1. **A** is a local repo, **B** is a local repo and **C** is the central remote repo. All are non-bare.
2. **A** makes a commit `c` and pushes it on **C**. **C** updates its .git folder and it's working tree accordingly to the changes in `c`. **Important**: "*updating the working tree*" in my mind means replacing the **C** working tree (i.e. **C** files and folders) with the **A** working tree.
3. **B** pulls the changes from **C** and updates its .git folder and working tree accordingly to the changes in `c`

How can a situation like the one described above can make the working tree of C out of sync? What does even mean that C goes out of sync?

The only true advantage that I understood so far is that for services like Github or Gitlab not maintaining a working tree (i.e. having a bare repo) for each repo and for each branch is very convenient to save storage space. They can reconstruct the working tree on the fly leveraging the Git tools.

Comment: What problem do *you* try to solve here?

Comment: @RomainValeri understading why Git implemented the concept of bare repo

Comment: Wouldn't your last paragraph be enough to justify their existence? Also, what do you mean by "logical" difference? Why would a real practical difference somehow not be enough? Genuinely asking, I could have missed something.

Comment: @RomainValeri yes, my last paragraph would be enough if there weren't a lot of threads and articles mentioning that that isn't the only motivation. The "true" motivation apparently is avoiding to manage an out-of-sync central working tree, but I really don't get how it could happen. 
With "logical" I mean: "from where is coming the need of implementing the concept of a --bare repo? What's the issue is it trying to solve?"

Comment: @RomainValeri also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534 is mentioning this case of the "working tree out of sync". It's saying "Each time you are pushing to a non-bare repo, you have no guarantee that its working tree will reflect what you are pushing"...why?

Comment: As I'm not part of the downvoters, I can only speculate. Maybe has it been read as an opinion question? There have been cases of people venting about a technology in form of a question (I don't think it's your case here), could it be that to someone?

Comment: @RomainValeri I agree. I actually upvoted because I came across this very imported question in my search for a related problem that required better understanding of the purpose and meaning of a bare git repository.

Comment: In addition, https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-push states that: *"A modern Git practice is to have a remotely hosted `--bare` repository act as a central origin repository. This origin repository is often hosted off-site with a trusted 3rd party. Since **pushing messes with the remote branch structure,** It is safest and most common to push to repositories that have been created with the `--bare` flag. Bare repos don’t have a working directory so **a push will not alter any in progress working directory content**."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's relatively simple, really.  A bare repository has no working tree, therefore it *cannot* have an active checkout.<sup>1</sup>  And, as you've seen elsewhere, the issue is that pushing *to* an active checkout of some branch results in an out-of-sync checkout.  So Git forbids pushing to the checked-out branch.<sup>2</sup>  By the fact that a bare repository has no working tree, and therefore no checked-out branch, a bare repository sidesteps the problem.

> What does even mean that [the non-bare central repo] goes out of sync?

Let's dispense with the third machine: we only need `client`, a non-bare repository, and `server`, the repository that should be but isn't bare.

On `server`, branch `main` is actively checked-out.  Someone may or may not be logged in to `server` and editing files there.

Meanwhile, on `client`, you've made some new commit and you run `git push` and send the new commit to `server`.  If the server accepts this commit, there are now two possibilities:

1. `server`'s Git repository *doesn't* update the checked-out working tree, or
2. `server`'s Git repository *does* update the checked-out working tree.

Both situations *can* produce a bad outcome.  Before we start on that, let's explore Git's workings a bit.

---

<sup>1</sup>This *was* true before `git worktree add` was added, and now it isn't.  So the simplicity was there until Git 2.5, and now it isn't.

<sup>2</sup>This *was* true in original Git, before the invention of various configuration items.  Now it isn't.  So the simplicity was there once, and now it isn't.  (The `receive.denyCurrentBranch` stuff happened before the `git worktree` command, but I don't recall offhand which version that was.)

---

#### Git is about commits; commits are numbered; branch names find commits

A Git repository consists mainly of two databases, one usually much larger than the other.  The larger database contains commits and supporting Git objects.  The smaller database contains names, such as branch and tag names.

The commit objects are numbered, with the numbers expressed as [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) hash IDs.  Git *needs* the hash ID to find the commit: the big database is indexed solely by hash ID.

A commit itself contains two things:

- a full snapshot of every file, as of the state it should have *for* that commit; and
- metadata: information about the commit itself, such as who made it, when, and why (a log message).

In the metadata for any given commit, Git stores the raw hash ID(s) of the *parent or parents* of that commit.  A commit therefore has a list of previous-commit hash IDs, stored in its metadata.  This forms the history in the repository.

To be able to obtain the *latest* commit for any given branch, Git stores, in the branch name (e.g., `refs/heads/main`), the raw hash ID of the *latest* commit.  That commit contains, in its metadata, the hash ID of the previous (parent) commit, which in turn contains another hash ID for another parent, and so on.

When we use `git checkout` or `git switch` with a branch name, we're telling Git: *extract the **latest** commit for that branch*.  That's the one whose hash ID is stored in the branch name.  So with `git switch main`, Git looks up `refs/heads/main`, finds a hash ID such as `a123456...`, and looks up that commit in the database.  That commit has a set of files associated with it.  Git copies those files out of the commit—the ones *in* the commit aren't generally usable by the OS, as they're in a read-only, compressed, Git-only, de-duplicated form—to your working tree.

But, Git *also* copies the files—or rather, information about the files (names and blob hash IDs)—into Git's *index*, which goes along with the working tree.  This defines which files are *tracked*, helps Git go fast, and is generally needed to know what to put in the *next* commit.

Once this is all in place, Git sets up the special name `HEAD` to contain the *branch name*.  (In original Git, this was a symbolic link to the `refs/heads/main` file, but as with many bits of Git, that was done away with more than a decade ago.)

There's now a group of well-defined, carefully-coordinated data:

- `HEAD` contains the *current branch name;*
- the branch name contains the hash ID;
- Git's index contains the file names and blob hash IDs for the *next* commit, tracking the files in the working tree; and
- the working tree contains the files copied out of the commit.

You work on the files, run `git add` to tell Git to update what's in Git's index, and eventually run `git commit`.  At this point Git:

- reads HEAD and then the branch name to find the current commit;
- collects all necessary metadata;
- packages up the index's content;
- writes all of this to a *new* commit, which gets a new unique hash ID; and
- writes the hash ID into the branch name.

The carefully-coordinated data lets Git do all of this, and is still carefully-coordinated.

#### If someone else commits while you're working ...

Now suppose we're on the server, working, and someone on the *client* commits.  That's not a problem because the client Git repository has *its own branch names*.  It gets a new commit in *its* commit database, and *its* branch name `main` stores a new hash ID.  But over here on `server`, *our* Git databases are unchanged.

But if they now run `git push main` and *send their commit*, our Git has to either accept their commit or reject it.  If we reject it, that's fine: our databases remain unchanged and everything is still coordinated.

Let's say that instead, though, we accept the push.  The server Git updates `refs/heads/main` to store *their* commit hash ID.  Our two possibilities are:

1. *don't* update index and working tree;
2. *do* update index and working tree.

If we choose possibility #1, then we have a "stale checkout": our files are from the previous commit.  But the *branch name* holds the new commit hash ID.  So we're out of sync.  If we update any files and then commit, we'll *revert the other guy's work* (remember that our Git software uses what's in our index, which matches our working tree).  That's not great, so let's move on to option 2.

If we choose option 2, our files get ripped away from us and replaced.  Our index and working tree are re-synchronized with the updated branch name.  That's better ... *except*, if we're actively *working on some file*, what happens to our work?  Maybe our editor notices that the underlying file has changed and gives us a chance to fix things.  Maybe it just overwrites the underlying file.  Either way, it's likely to be a problem.

So, updating the working tree of a server's repository *is* perhaps better than not doing that, and that's what `receive.denyCurrentBranch`'s `updateInstead` setting does.  It's not perfect, though.  "Perfect" is just *don't have a working tree so that nothing can go wrong*, and we get that with `--bare`.

Comment: Thanks a LOT, this is exactly what I was looking for and even more. Now it's crystal clear. I wasn't fully understanding because I was biased by how we are used to using Git with services like GitHub. I've always associated GitHub as the "server" of your example and therefore a repo you cannot really interact with (e.g. checkout, commit, etc...). However, if we think the "server" as a machine we have access to, then the out-of-sync situation makes totally sense!