# Git rebase vs checkout

Tags: git, branch, git-rebase, git-checkout

It's been a while that whenever I want to review new changes in a branch (remote/local) I am doing a `checkout` to that branch, but recently I came across `rebase` command which seems to be created for such purposes, I am wondering about the difference between these two approaches. Can someone explain it in a simple way?

```
git checkout <branch_name>

git rebase <branch_name>
```

Comment: This question isn't very clear because your goal of "I want to review new changes in a branch" doesn't require either `checkout` or `rebase`. Perhaps it would help if you gave some branch names for both the local and remote branches, with an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: "recently I came across rebase command which seems to be created for such purposes" No it's not. Where did you "come accross" this? Sounds like a misunderstood advice.

Comment: @RomainValeri my hunch is that OP is trying to do something other than stated, and that rebase may in fact be one way to accomplish the true intention.

Comment: @TTT Yes you might very well be right. Let's let OP clear this up.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I usually need to review codes from other colleagues when they are done with some tasks, then I simple checkout to their branches and do my review, so far I was suing checkout for this, but from what rebase means in general context based on my understanding, maybe wrong, I switch "the base" of my local branch to my colleague branch and that's it. However from the @torek answer I feel I have got wrong understanding, I will dive deeper into this.

Answer (score 3):

Rebase and checkout are wildly different commands, with different *goals*.  Neither goal exactly matches your own—which is or seems to be to *inspect* something—but checkout comes **much** closer.

> Can someone explain it Eli5?

I'm afraid I blow right past the vocabulary limits for that  but let's start with the proper basics, which too many Git users have skipped (for reasons good or bad, but the end result was bad).

#### Git is about commits

The basic unit of storage in Git is the *commit*.  A Git *repository* is a collection of commits, stored in a big database that Git calls the *object database*.  A Git repository has several more parts, which we'll get to in a moment, but this first one—the object database—is essential: without it there's no *repository*.

The object database is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), using what Git calls *OIDs* or Object IDs to look up the objects.  The most important kind of object for our purposes—in fact, the only one we really care about—is the commit object, which holds the first part of any commit.  So our commits, in Git, have these OIDs.  We'll call them *hash IDs* to avoid getting caught up in too many TLAs—Three Letter Acronyms—and probably, eventually, [RAS syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome).  Some call them SHA or SHA-1, because Git initially (and currently) uses the SHA-1 crytographic hash as its hash IDs, but Git is no longer wedded to SHA-1, so "hash ID" or "OID" is more appropriate.

An OID or hash ID is a big ugly string of letters and digits, such as [<sup>`e54793a95afeea1e10de1e5ad7eab914e7416250`</sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e54793a95afeea1e10de1e5ad7eab914e7416250).  This is actually a very large number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  Git *needs* these to find its objects.  The ID is unique to that particular object: no *other* object, in the big objects database, can have that ID.  Every *commit* you make has to get a *new* random-looking number, never-before-used, never to be used again *ever*, in *any* Git repository, unless it's being used to store *your commit*.  Making this actually work is hard—technically, it's impossible<sup>1</sup>—but the sheer size of the hash ID makes it work *in practice*.  A Git doomsday may come someday (see [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)) but it won't be for a while yet.

---

<sup>1</sup>See the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

---

#### Git is *not* about branches or files

If Git commits did not store files, Git would be useless.  So commits *do* **store** files.  But commits are not files themselves, and a file is not Git's "unit of work" as it were.  Git is about the *commits*, which sort of accidentally-on-purpose *contain* files.

The word *branch*, in Git, is very badly overused, almost to the point of meaninglessness.<sup>2</sup>  There are at least two or three things people mean when they say *branch* here, and it can get very confusing, although once you've got the basics down you'll find yourself right among all the other people casually tossing the word *branch* out in a sentence, maybe more than once in the same sentence, with each word meaning something different, yet the whole thing seems totally obvious.

To help keep this straight, I like to (try at least) to use the phrase *branch name* when referring to a name like `main` or `master`, `dev` or `develop`, `feature`, and so on.  A *branch name*, in Git, is a fast and important way to *find* **one particular commit**.  Humans use these because human brains are no good at working with hash IDs: they're too big, ugly, and random-looking.

A repository therefore keeps a separate database—another simple key-value store—in which each key is a *name* and the value is the big ugly hash ID that goes with that name.  Branch names are one of the many kinds of names that Git sticks in this second database.  So, you can give Git a branch name; Git will look up the hash ID, and find the *latest commit* for that branch.

In this sense, we use branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—in Git to get to our commits.  But Git isn't about these branches, really; it's still about the *commits*.

---

<sup>2</sup>For an even more extreme example of this problem, see [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).  For more on Git's abuse of the word *branch*, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

---

#### What's in a commit

Now that we know Git is all about commits, let's take a look at an actual raw commit.  Here's the one I referred to above:

```
$ git cat-file -p e54793a95afeea1e10de1e5ad7eab914e7416250
tree dc3d0156b95303a305c69ba9113c94ff114b7cd3
parent 565442c35884e320633328218e0f6dd13f3657d3
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1651786597 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1651786597 -0700

Git 2.36.1

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

That's the raw commit *object*, and it actually consists entirely of the commit's *metadata*.

A commit object has two parts:

- Every commit has a *full snapshot* of all of the files that make up that particular commit.  In a real commit like the one above, that's the `tree` line, which is required: there must be one and only one `tree`.
- Every commit also has some *metadata*.  That's the entire chunk of text above, really (including the `tree` line itself).

Note that the metadata tells us who made the commit, and when: the magic number `1651786597` above is a date-and-time-stamp meaning `Thu May 5 14:36:37 2022`.  The `-0700` is the time zone, which in this case is Pacific Daylight Time or UTC-7.  (It could be Mountain Standard Time which is also UTC-7, and is in use right now in the Navajo Nation areas of Arizona, but you can pretty safely bet that this was not Junio Hamano's actual location at the time.)  It also has the committer's commit *message*, which in this case is remarkably short: compare with, e.g., a snippet from [<sup><sub>`f8781bfda31756acdc0ae77da7e70337aedae7c9`</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8781bfda31756acdc0ae77da7e70337aedae7c9):

```
2.36 gitk/diff-tree --stdin regression fix

This only surfaced as a regression after 2.36 release, but the
breakage was already there with us for at least a year.

The diff_free() call is to be used after we completely finished with
a diffopt structure.  After "git diff A B" finishes producing
output, calling it before process exit is fine.  But there are
commands that prepares diff_options struct once, compares two sets
of paths, releases resources that were used to do the comparison,
then reuses the same diff_option struct to go on to compare the next
two sets of paths, like "git log -p".

After "git log -p" finishes showing a single commit, calling it
before it goes on to the next commit is NOT fine.  There is a
mechanism, the .no_free member in diff_options struct, to help "git
log" to avoid calling diff_free() after showing each commit and ...
```

which is a much better commit message.  (Excluding the updated tests and a comment in `log-tree.c`, the fix itself just adds three lines to `builtin/diff-tree.c`.)

The other *really important* part of the metadata, which Git sets up on its own, is the `parent` line.  There can be more than one `parent` line—or, rarely, *no* parent line—because each commit carries, in its metadata, a *list* of parent hash IDs.  These are just the raw hash IDs of some existing commits in the repository, that were there when you, or Junio, or whoever, added a *new* commit.  We'll see in a moment what these are for.

#### Review so far

A *repository* has two databases:

- One (usually much bigger) contains commits and other objects.  These have hash IDs; Git *needs* the hash IDs to find them.
- The other (usually much smaller) contains *names*, such as branch and tag names, and maps each name to *one* hash ID.  For a branch name, the one hash ID we get here is, by definition, the *latest commit for that branch*.
- The *commits* are the reason that all of this exists.  Each one stores two things: a full snapshot, and some metadata.

#### A working tree

Now, one of the tricks to making the hash IDs work, in Git, is that *no part of any object can ever change*.  A commit, once made, is the way it is *forever*.  That commit, with that hash ID, holds *those files* and *that metadata* and thus has *that parent* (or those parents) and so on.  **Everything is frozen for all time.**

The files inside a commit are stored in a special, read-only, compressed (sometimes highly compressed), *de-duplicated* format.  That avoids having the repository bloat up even though most commits mostly re-use most of the files from their parent commit(s).  Because the files are de-duplicated, the duplicates literally take no space.  Only a *changed* file needs any space.

But there's an obvious problem:

- Only *Git* can *read* these compressed-and-de-duplicated files.
- Nothing, not even Git itself, can *write* them.

If we're going to get any work done, we must have *ordinary files*, that ordinary programs can both read *and write*.  Where will we get those?

Git's answer is to provide, with any *non-bare* repository,<sup>3</sup> an area in which you can do your work.  Git calls this area—a directory-tree or folder full of folders, or whatever terminology you like—your *working tree*, or *work-tree* for short.  In fact, the typical setup is to have the repository proper live inside a hidden `.git` directory at the top level *of* the working tree.  Everything inside this is *Git's;* everything outside it, at the top level of the working tree and in any sub-directory (folder) within it other than `.git` itself, is *yours*.

---

<sup>3</sup>A *bare* repository is one without a work-tree.  This might seem kind of redundant or pointless, but it does actually have a function: see [What problem is trying to solve a Git --bare repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72116221/1256452)

---

#### What `git checkout` or `git switch` is about

When you *check out* some commit—with `git checkout` or `git switch` and a branch name—you're telling Git:

- Use the branch name to find the latest commit by hash ID.
- Remove, from my working tree, all the files that came out of whatever commit I've been using.
- Replace, into my working tree, all the files that come out of the commit I just named.

Git takes a big short-cut here when it can: if you're moving from commit `a123456` to `b789abc`, and most of the files in those two commits are de-duplicated, Git won't actually bother with the remove-and-replace for these files.  This short-cut becomes important later, but if you start out thinking of `git checkout` / `git switch` as meaning: *remove the current commit's files, change to a new current commit, and extract those files* you have a good start.

#### How commits get strung together

Let's revisit the commit itself for a bit now.  Each commit has, in its metadata, some set of `parent` lines.  *Most* commits (by far in most repositories) have exactly one parent and that's the thing to start with.

Let's *draw* the commits in a simple, tiny, three-commit repository.  The three commits will have three big ugly random-looking hash IDs, but rather than make some up, let's just call them commits `A`, `B`, and `C` in that order.  Commit `A` was the very first commit—which is a bit special because it has *no* parent commit—and then you made `B` while *using* commit `A`, and made `C` while using `B`.  So we have this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

That is, commit `C`, the *latest* commit, has some files as its snapshot, and has, as its parent, the raw hash ID of commit `B`.  We say that `C` *points to* `B`.

Meanwhile, commit `B` has some files as its snapshot, and has commit `A` as its parent.  We say that `B` points to `A`.

Your *branch name*, which we'll assume is `main`, *points to* the latest commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

(here I get lazy about drawing the arrows between commits *as* arrows, but they're still backwards-pointing arrows, really).

When you `git checkout main`, Git extracts all the commit-`C` files into your working tree.  You have those files available to view and edit.

If you do edit some, you use `git add` and `git commit` to make a *new commit*.  This new commit gets an all-new, never been used before anywhere in any Git repository in the universe, hash ID, but we'll just call this new commit `D`.  Git will arrange for new commit `D` to point backwards to existing commit `C`, because `C` is the one you've been using, so let's draw in new commit `D`:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D
```

(The backwards slash going up-and-left from `D` to `C` is why I get lazy about the arrows—there are some arrow fonts but they don't work all that well on StackOverflow, so we just have to imagine the arrow from `D` to `C`.)

But now `D` *is* the *latest* `main` commit, so `git commit` *also stores `D`'s hash ID into the name `main`* so that `main` now points to `D`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- main
```

(and now there's no reason to use extra lines to draw things; I just kept it for visual symmetry).

**This is one way a branch grows, in Git.**  You *check out* the branch, so that it's your *current branch*.  Its tip-most commit—the one towards the right in this drawing, or towards the top in `git log --graph` output—becomes your *current commit* and those are the files you see in your working tree.  You edit those files, use `git add`, and run `git commit`, and Git packages up the *new* files—with automatic de-duplication, so that if you change a file *back* to the way it was in `B` or `A`, it gets de-duplicated here!—into a new commit, then stuffs the *new* commit's hash ID into the current branch name.

#### How branches form

Let's say we start out with that same three-commit repository:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

Let's now create a *new branch name* `dev`.  This name *must point to some existing commit*.  There are only three commits, so we have to pick one of `A`, `B`, or `C`, for the name `dev` to point-to.  The obvious one to use is the most recent: we probably don't need to go back in time to commit `B` or `A` to start adding new commits.  So let's add `dev` so that it *also* points to `C`, by running:

```
git branch dev
```

We get:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev, main
```

It's hard to tell from our drawing: are we on `dev` or `main`?  That is, if we run `git status`, which will it say, "on branch dev" or "on branch main"?  Let's add a special name, `HEAD` in all uppercase like this, and *attach it* to one of the two branch names, to show which *name* we are using:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev, main (HEAD)
```

We are "on" branch `main`.  If we make a new commit now, commit `D` will point back to commit `C` as usual, and Git will stick the new hash ID into the *name* `main`.

But if we run:

```
git checkout dev
```

Git will remove, from our working tree, all the commit-`C` files, and put in all the commit-`C` files instead.  (Seems kind of silly, doesn't it?  Short-cut!  Git won't actually *do* any of that!)  Now we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD), main
```

and when we make our new commit `D` we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

If we `git checkout main`, Git will remove the commit-`D` files and install the commit-`C` files, and we'll be back to:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- dev
```

and if we now make *another* new commit we will get:

```
        E   <-- main (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- dev
```

**This is how branches work in Git.**  A branch *name*, like `main` or `dev`, picks out a *last* commit.  From there, *Git works backwards*.  Commit `E` might be the last `main` commit, but commits `A-B-C` are *on* `main` because we get to them when we start from `E` and work backwards.

Meanwhile, commit `D` is the last `dev` commit, but commits `A-B-C` are *on* `dev` because we get to them when we start from `D` and work backwards.  Commit `D` is *not* on `main` because we never reach commit `D` when we start from `E` and work backwards: that skips right over `D`.

#### Review

We now know:

- Git is about *commits*.
- Commits store snapshots and metadata.
- We organize the commits into branches using *branch names* to find the *last* commit.
- We *check out* a commit to see its files *as files*, and to work on them.  Otherwise they're special weird Gitty things that only Git can see.
- No part of any commit can ever change, once it's made.

Now we'll get to `git rebase`.

#### What `git rebase` is about

We often find ourselves using Git and stuck in this kind of situation:

```
          F--G--H   <-- main
         /
...--A--B
         \
          C--D--E   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

and we say to ourselves: *Gosh, it would be nice if we had started out feature later, when `main` had commit `G` and/or `H` in it, because we need what's in those now.*

There's nothing fundamentally *wrong* with commits `C-D-E` and we could just use `git merge`, but for whatever reason—the boss says so, the co-workers have decided they like a rebase flow, whatever it might be—we decide that we're going to "improve" our `C-D-E` commits.  We're going to *re-make them* so that they come *after* `F-G-H`, like this:

```
                  C'-D'-E'   <-- improved-feature (HEAD)
                 /
          F--G--H   <-- main
         /
...--A--B
         \
          C--D--E   <-- feature
```

We can, quite literally, do this by *check out* commit `H`, making a new branch, and then re-doing our work:

```
git switch main
git switch -c improved-feature
... redo a bunch of work ...
```

What `git rebase` does is automate this for us.  If we were to do it manually, each "redo" step would involve using `git cherry-pick` (which I won't go into in any detail here).  The `git rebase` command *automates* the cherry-picking for us, and then adds one other twist: instead of requiring a *new* branch name like `improved-feature`, it simply yanks the old branch name off the old commits and makes it point to the new ones:

```
                  C'-D'-E'   <-- feature (HEAD)
                 /
          F--G--H   <-- main
         /
...--A--B
         \
          C--D--E   [abandoned]
```

The old abandoned commits are actually still there, in Git, for at least 30 days or so.  But with no *name* by which to *find* them, you can only *see* those commits if you have saved their hash IDs, or have some trick by which to find those hash IDs.<sup>4</sup>

When the rebase finishes completely, our original commits are copied to new-and-improved commits.  The new commits have new and different hash IDs, but since no human ever notices the actual hash IDs, a human who looks at this repository just sees three `feature`-branch-only commits and *assumes* they have magically been changed into the new improved ones.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>Git comes with some handy tricks built-in, but we won't cover them here.

<sup>5</sup>Git sees the truth, and if you connect your Git repository to some other Git repository, they will have ... words, or a long conversation, about this and it can make a big mess if you don't know what you're doing.  Basically, if *they* still have your originals, you can wind up getting them back when you *thought* you'd gotten rid of them!  Any time you connect two Git repositories, you generally have one hand over any new commits it has that the other one is missing.  This is where the magic of the hash IDs really comes into effect: they do this all by hash ID alone.

The bottom line here is that you should only rebase commits when *all users of those commits agree* that those commits can be rebased.  If you're the only user, you just have to agree with yourself, so that's a lot easier.  Otherwise, get agreement in advance from all *other* users before you start rebasing.

Comment: It's a nitpick, but Git has mutable history. Saying that Git history or specific commits are immutable is just plain wrong, although I understood your goal in trying to explain it to the OP that way. There are other SCMs that offer immutable history, but Git isn't one of them. If it were, force-push and rebase wouldn't be available (as just two key examples).

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs: The *commits* don't change. History changes *if and only if* you view history as "that which is reachable from a name", because the names *do* change.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, that I fear may be overkill, given that it's not entirely clear what the OP is asking in the first place. Hopefully this is useful to them.

Comment: You're missing the core concept of how a commitish relates to a treeish, and how Git tracks history. Blobs and trees may or may not change, but while Git is a DAG it isn't an immutable blockchain. You can make modifications anywhere within the DAG and the ancestry (and thus the "history") will change as well. This is *important* to understanding Git, just as it's important to understand that Git tracks *content* rather than files or directories as first-class items. Conceptually, most commits are just a snapshot of pointers to collections of hashes at a given checkpoint.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs: I'm as error-prone as anyone, but I think I *have* covered that above, particularly with the part about rebase. When we rebase, we change the commit selected by some *name*. That changes which commits we *see* in the DAG, when we choose the *name*. The commit-ish vs tree-ish is also covered above: a commit *represents* a tree and there's a one-to-one mapping from commit to tree (but not vice versa, it's a surjection from commit to tree, not a bijection).

Comment: Guys, I am still not clear on what is the correct way for me to test the work of another colleague, is it `git switch` or `git checkout` to his/her branch?, but overall I know that rebase has a different usage that what I originally thought about!

Comment: @NaserNikzad: Generally you want `git checkout` or `git switch`. For instance, `git switch --detach origin/theirbranch` will get you a detached HEAD from which you can build and test their commit.

Answer (score 0):

To review a remote branch (I don't have yet), I prefer [`git switch aBranch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch): its [guess mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess) would automatically set a remote tracking branch `origin/aBranch`, allowing me to do simple `git pull` to update it in the future review instances.

That would be the same as `git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`

I also prefer setting

```bash
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, a `git pull` on that branch would rebase any of my local commits on top of the updated branch, not only for my review, but also to check if my local (not yet pushed) code/commits still work on top of the updated remote branch.