# Can't find my git repository url

Tags: linux, git, git-push, git-clone

So I think I am confused - but for some reason I cannot `push` or `pull` to my git repository.

I have a linux web server and have a web folder in `/var/www/bcs.net.nz/`

I did a `git init bcs.git` in this folder (I have also tried `.git`) 
and then I thought I could do `git clone git@bcs.net.nz:bcs.git` to clone it on the local machine or `git push` on the remote machine.

I have also added a `git remote add origin git@bcs.net.nz:bcs.git` on the remote machine.

After all of that I still cannot push and pull anything.
I am a bit stuck.

`git add .` & `git commit -m "initial commit"` work fine.

Comment: Look at bare repositories documentation

Comment: I am doing that and have been doing that, but it is not getting me anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone git@bcs.net.nz:bcs.git` would mean to clone a (preferably **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26687327/6309)**) which is in `/home/git/bcs.git`

You could initialize one there, (`git init --bare /home/git/bcs.git`), and add a [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) (`chmod 755 /home/git/bcs.git/hooks/post-receive`) which will checkout the code in the live server folder

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/bcs.net.nz --git-dir=/home/git/bcs.git checkout -f
```

Comment: This is starting to make sense - just one thing - is that hook placed from within the bcs.git repo? I am not sure where the .git is? is I have created bcs.git

Comment: @JeffKranenburg a bare repo is it own .git, it has no .git since it is the .git. I have edited the answer accordingly.