# Can I add a second website to gitlab-ce?

Tags: nginx, gitlab, gitlab-ce

Anyone have a quick explanation / good link to an guide to adding a secondary website to a gitlab-ce instance?

Ie, A separately hosted website - aka a separate folder with my own content, accessible from say, `gitlab.example.com/new_site/`, whether just static files or otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean "secondary website"? Another remote to push to? Another wiki?

Comment: A separately hosted website - aka a separate folder with my own content, accessible from say, gitlab.example.com/new_site/, whether just static files or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> A separately hosted website - aka a separate folder with my own content, accessible from say, gitlab.example.com/new_site

That looks like [GitLab pages](http://pages.gitlab.io/), which are for now an enterprise edition feature.

8.16 should bring GitLAb page to the community edition though.
See "[We’re bringing GitLab Pages to the Community Edition](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/24/were-bringing-gitlab-pages-to-community-edition/) "

Comment: Sure, GitLab pages would do it - but I'm thinking that nginx allows multiple sites via Server-Blocks, similar to Apache's virtual hosts.  Or does Gitlab's .rb file not allow custom nginx config information?

Comment: @John if you control the server side and its own NGiNX server,then you can serve any page you want from any Git repo (GitLab or otherwise): GitLab store any file, not just rb ruby ones. Simply set a post-receive hook: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30725069/6309