# How to sync remote and local Git repositories

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

I have created one test repository on Git server/website (https://github.com/cMaheshwari09/testing.git), I have done clone this to my localhost also. Now I can **PUSH** and **PULL** perfectly from my local machine to Git server.

But now I want to deploy code on my live server but not using FTP or any other file transfer method/tool. I want to upload my files using Git push method. It means that I want to sync my localhost repository to live server directly using Git.

So when I make any changes to my local, then I can commit that changes to Git server as well as live server too.

I have gone through so many different documents and tutorials, but I can't find any simple way or straight-forward way to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the post-receive Git hook for this
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

The hook will look like this

```
cd [LIVE SITE DIR] && git pull origin master
```

I will describe how I have my deployment set up. I use the same server as live server and as a place where I have my repositories stored.

- I store my Git repositories in `/var/git directory`. Applications are stored in `/var/www`
- Create Git repository using `git init --bare`

  ```
  cd /var/git
  mkdir project.git
  cd project.git
  git init --bare
  ```
- Clone repository into the `/var/www/project` folder
- Clone repository to my local computer
- Create post-receive hook

  ```
  cd /var/git/project.git/hooks
  touch post-receive
  chmod +x post-receive
  ```

The post-receive hook looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    unset GIT_DIR
    cd /var/www/project && git pull origin master
```

If you do not unset GIT_DIR, you will get the following error when doing git push:

```
    remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

It's because Git uses the variable GIT_DIR instead of PWD. See more information about this here:
[getting "fatal: not a git repository: '.'" when using post-update hook to execute 'git pull' on another repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043609/getting-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-using-post-update-hook-to-execut)

When you do changes on your local computer, commit them and push them, these changes will be automatically pulled into the /var/www/project directory.

If you have one server as live server and your repositories are stored on another server. You will have to change your post-receive hook so you would ssh to the live server and execute the git pull origin master there.

Comment: Can you please send me steps or full details regarding how to setup or what i need to do so that my live server can connect with my git repository/local repository.

Comment: Edited my answer based on your request.